# Template10 SettingsService exception

Tags: visual-studio-2015, template10

Using Template10 1.18, and when suspending App in VisualStudio (using lifecycle events), I am seeing "the size of the state manager setting value has exceeded the limit". As seen in the stack trace below, Template10.Services.SettingsService.SettingsService.Write is directly involved. I know one answer is to not use the Setting service, and do file writes for data when suspending, but Template10 is handling this so it seems best to let it. 
If I must turn off Template10 Setting service, how? Or can I override the method and avoid using LocalSettings?

> NMA-Client.McgInterop.dll!System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.IMapSharedReferenceTypesStubClass.Insert(System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary
>   _this, string key, object value) Line 2176    C#      NMA-Client.McgInterop.dll!Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataCompositeValue.System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary.set_Item(string
>   index, object value) Line 9704    C# 
>     Template10Library.dll!Template10.Services.SettingsService.SettingsService.Write(string
>   key, string value)    Unknown 
>     Template10Library.dll!Template10.Services.NavigationService.NavigationService.SaveNavigationAsync() Unknown
>     Template10Library.dll!Template10.Services.NavigationService.NavigationService.SaveNavigationAsync() Unknown
>     Template10Library.dll!Template10.Services.NavigationService.NavigationService.SuspendingAsync() Unknown
>     Template10Library.dll!Template10.Services.NavigationService.NavigationService.SuspendingAsync() Unknown
>     Template10Library.dll!Template10.Common.BootStrapper.HandleSuspending() Unknown
>     Template10Library.dll!Template10.Common.BootStrapper.HandleSuspending.AnonymousMethod__2()  Unknown
>     Template10Library.dll!Template10.Common.DispatcherWrapper.DispatchAsync()   Unknown
>     Template10Library.dll!Template10.Common.DispatcherWrapper.DispatchAsync(System.Func
>   func, int delayms, Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority
>   priority) Unknown 
>     Template10Library.dll!Template10.Common.BootStrapper.HandleSuspending() Unknown
>     Template10Library.dll!Template10.Common.BootStrapper.HandleSuspending(object
>   sender, Windows.ApplicationModel.SuspendingEventArgs e)   Unknown 
>     System.Private.SharedLibrary.Interop.Generated.dll!Windows.Foundation.AsyncOperationProgressHandler.Invoke(Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperationWithProgress
>   asyncInfo, uint progressInfo) C# 
>     NMA-Client.McgInterop.dll!McgInterop.ReverseComSharedStubs.Proc_object__TArg0__(object
>   __this, System.Runtime.InteropServices.__vtable_IInspectable* unsafe_sender, void* unsafe_e, System.IntPtr __methodPtr) Line 9745 C#
>     NMA-Client.McgInterop.dll!Windows.UI.Xaml.SuspendingEventHandler__Impl.Vtbl.Invoke__STUB(System.IntPtr
>   pComThis, System.Runtime.InteropServices.__vtable_IInspectable*
>   unsafe_sender,
>   Windows.ApplicationModel.ISuspendingEventArgs__Impl.Vtbl** unsafe_e)
>   Line 94537    C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Template 10 `SettingService` is a generic wrapper for `SettingHelper` intended for 90% of developers. It appears your app needs a special implementation. You can copy the existing SettingsService into your project to solve your problem. I realize SettingService won't work for 10% of the apps out there. You are one of the lucky 10%. But your custom wrapper should solve this.

Get the source here https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/blob/master/Template10%20(Library)/Services/SettingsService/SettingsService.cs

Comment: Thanks Jerry, I thought this answer was likely but just wanted to make sure.